# Как работать с GDI Handle

Tags: c#, gdi

Сидел я в Process Hacker и заметил что есть вкладка GDI Handle, зашёл, а там: Region, Brush, Bitmap.
Как можно с ними работать? Например, Получить Region, Brush, Bitmap или даже изменить их.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Информации вообще нет ;(

Comment: Совершенно не понятно что вы хотите, но если я правильно понимаю - вы хотели вытащить картинку в свое(своим) приложение?

Comment: Я хочу изменить свойства Brush и получать картинку с игры с помощью этого.
Приложение - Minecraft

Comment: Предлагаю вам забыть этот вариант сразу :) Если вам интересно изменить вывод приложения - ищите "перехват D3D & OpenGL", если хотите снимать "скриншоты" - вызывайте системную функцию, гуглить на тему ```bitblt```

Comment: Да мне это не так интересно.
Просто если серьёзно есть способ легко получить или даже изменить Картинку или кисть приложения я бы хотел в этом разобраться

Comment: Выбранное вами приложение не использует GDI для отображения графики, соответственно ваша попытка изменить или получить содержимое таким путем - обречено на провал. Оно использует либо OpenGL либо D3D (скорее первое)

Comment: Почему тогда не во всех процессах есть эти хендлеры, я всё же хочу разобраться с ними

Comment: Если хотите разобраться с ними - возьмите приложение с "кнопками" и "формой", например калькулятор windows неплохо можно разобрать на атомы и менять шрифты кисти и прочее из своего приложения. Для этого вам понадобятся как минимум "привилегии отладчика"